# Batch script for XP to rename file and copy to new folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I have hundreds image files. I want to do 2 tasks with batch script.

1) I want to rename files with the name without '_' if any file have and move them to temp folder.

2) if any file duplicates with file name then take it any of the file and move it to specified temp folder.

Anyone knows how to do this? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Let me see if I understand...

(1) for all files in directory if filename contains a _ move it to temp with _ removed.

(2) ????

Answer (score 1):

for the renaming part...you could try this approch...

```
@echo on
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f %%i in ('dir *.txt /b/a-d') do (
set name=%%i
set name=!name:_=!
ren %%i !name!
)
```

For the file moving part...could you please elaborate the requirement a little more?

--Nihar